# Deploy angular app using capistrano

Tags: angular, npm, capistrano, npm-install

I don't know if it's the best way but I would like to use capistrano (through gitlab-ci) to deploy my angular 5 app on a remote server.

I have a problem with npm install and ng build. The node_modules seems to be empty for capistrano. Here the config file.

## deploy.rb

```
set :application, 'bo'
set :repo_url, 'git@...'
set :keep_releases, 5

set :deploy_via, "remote_cache_with_project_root"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/bo/"
set :current_directory, "bo"
set :npm_flags, '--production' # default

after 'deploy:published','test:npm_install'
after 'deploy:published','test:build'

...
```

## tasks

## npm_install.cap

```
namespace :test do
    desc 'build bo'
    task :npm_install do 
        on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
            execute :npm, "install"
        end
    end
end

...
```

## build.cap

```
namespace :test do
    desc 'build bo'
    task :build do 
        on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
            execute "ng build --aot --env=prod --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks"
        end
    end
end

....
```

Errors I can see in gitlab-ci :

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as bo@test.intra: ng build --aot --env=prod --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks exit status: 1
ng build --aot --env=prod --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks stdout: Nothing written
ng build --aot --env=prod --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks stderr: node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/7599a2f4/0/bo/deploy/tasks/build.cap:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: ng build --aot --env=prod --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks exit status: 1
ng build --aot --env=prod --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks stdout: Nothing written
ng build --aot --env=prod --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks stderr: node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/7599a2f4/0/bo/deploy/tasks/build.cap:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/7599a2f4/0/bo/deploy/tasks/build.cap:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I'm using gitlab to generate the build and capistrano to manage the releases ;)